# Insert or update a list (objects - with additional fields) based on another list in C# EF Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two lists, list A and list B. I want to insert/update ListB based on listA.

I have around 50k records. If I do it using foreach in list A it is taking 1 minute per 500 record to insert/update and save in SQL Server.

Is there a better way to do it? How do I achieve it with `SqlBulkCopy`?

How do I iterate through list efficiently without doing n*n iterations?

List A:

```
ID Name Age Address 
---------------------
1  abc  5   address11
2  de   67  address12
3  ac   55  address13
4  ffc  2   address14
5  cg   7   address15
```

List B:

```
ID Name Age Address    DateUpdated DatedAdded
----------------------------------------------
1  abc  5   address11  1/1/2023    1/1/2023
2  cg   7   address84  2/2/2023    1/1/2023
```

List C (Result)

```
ID Name Age Address    DateUpdated DatedAdded
---------------------------------------------
1  abc   5   address11  6/1/2023    1/1/2023
2  cg    7   address15  6/1/2023    1/1/2023 
3  de   67   address12  6/1/2023    6/1/2023 

4  ac   55   address13  6/1/2023    6/1/2023
5  ffc   2   address14  6/1/2023    6/1/2023
```

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: A stored procedure could help with your performance issue

Comment: You will never get the performance you seek from EF. Stored procedure would be a good option.